# Can I extend the number of days that the Track Changes history is kept for using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some VBA code that will save and share a workbook automatically. I would like to track changes in the workbook but I need to extend the number of days that the history is kept for from 30 to 1500.

I don't know if the number of days can be extended through VBA but confirmation would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please read your own question. Pretend that it's ssomeone else that has written it. Can you understand it with the information above?

Comment: Is the amended version easier to understand? I couldn't quite word it right but a good night's sleep has refreshed the senses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    If .KeepChangeHistory Then
        .ChangeHistoryDuration = 1500  'days
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Kostas K. The list of properties in ActiveWorkbook is long so I didn't see the .ChangeHistoryDuration